# How to increment count to my default label in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to increment the count of the value each time when I click on the new widget.

Whenever I click my new button I need to get incremented by +1 (e.g. Chart1, Chart2, Chart3)

As of now my values are stored in the state, so when I click add it gets incremented (Chart1, Chart2) but if I refresh the page again it starts with Chart1.

Here is my code

```
this.state = {
widgetCount: 1,
widgetName: '',
}

addWidget = (widgetType) => {
this.showChartTypesModal.hide();
const newWidget = this.getNewWidget(widgetType);
this.setState(
  {
    widgetsList: [...this.state.widgetsList, newWidget],
    isHidden: !this.state.isHidden,
    widgetCount: this.state.widgetCount + 1,
  },
  () => this.props.storyboardActions.addWidget(newWidget, 
 this.props.selectedBoard.boardId, updatedSwimlanes)
  );
  };

  case 'bar':
    return {
      widgetName: this.state.widgetName || `Chart ${this.state.widgetCount}`,
     };
  case 'pie':
    return {
      widgetName: this.state.widgetName || `Chart ${this.state.widgetCount}`,
     };
```

Should I use redux to maintain the state? Or is it possible to do without that.
Please help me with this

Comment: You're going to need to manage date of the state outside of the component. When you refresh so will the state.  Try this https://www.robinwieruch.de/local-storage-react/

Answer (score 1):

State is transient as HTTP is stateless. You need to save it in browser or in external database.
*I am assuming that by "refresh" you are refreshing the browser.*

Redux won't help you at all in this case.

If you want to persist the state across browser refresh, here are some options.

1. Use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) - stored in a browser
2. Use [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) - stored in a browser
3. Persist state/data in external database - firebase/postgres/mysql, etc.

Benefit of first two options is that, it's easy to implement, but it won't survive when a user refreshes the browser cache.
3rd option is the hardest but it will persist the state regardless of browser setting.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, State in redux does not persist. However, there is a library that will address this issue if you need persistence: [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). This would mean that the state does not reset after each refresh.